# Redirecting invalid URLs to a 404 page

Tags: javascript, html, url, web

I have a website http://html1.freeiz.com and if an invalid URL for the website is entered I want the user to be redirected to  http://html1.freeiz.com/Page_not_Found_404.html

Comment: So you mean you want to be redirected to `Page_not_Found_404.html` when non-existent pages are requested? You would need to make changes on the server, and you haven't mentioned what server you are using. You cannot do this purely in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Apache, and Linux or Unix Server you can do it like this with `.htaccess`:

1. Create a file in the Home Directory called `.htaccess`. the `.` is important(if there isn't already one).
2. Type in `ErrorDocument 404 /Page_not_Found_404.html`

http://www.404-error-page.com/404-create-a-custom-404-error-page-with-htaccess.shtml
Additionally, most hosting provide a tool to do this. If you are using cPanel, follow [this article](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/setting-a-404-error-page-via-htaccess)

> As a general rule, if your server runs Unix or Linux, or any version of the Apache web server it will support .htaccess, although your host may not allow you to use it.
>   [<sup>Source</sup>](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess)